# Obtain current Oauth access token C#

Tags: c#, oauth

I have an web application that uses Oauth for validate users.  The users can consume some services of the website  through   a mobile App. When the user signs in through the mobile app a service sends the generated  Oauth acces token to the   mobileapp . The thing is that I want for some mobile users keep them always validated.  By default I have  setting 14 days  token's life.

what I tried to do is generate a service that  mobile app sends back the username and the  access token  sended to the mobile app. the logic is simple, I want comapare the  token from Mobile App with  existing Token, if they are the same then I renew the token.  but I  cant find where  can I get the access token in the application. I've been looking around the  web and no answer founded yet.

Some say that I  need  save the generated access token when users signs in on a table and then when the  mobile app sends the token validate it against the saved token but I think that there must exist a place  (object) where Oauth access tokens are placed

Where can I found or access to the  Oauth access tokens generated  in my application? I mean the existing ones

Comment: Can you post some code to see what have you tried?

Comment: Why is this question tagged model-view-controller?